# HP running win7 pro --

Tags: boot

It get this message;

error: no boot disk has been detected or hard drive has failed

BTW: This is my friend's PC, I'm posting from my clone built PC running win 7 home premand trying to help him. He dided burn win7 from the hidden partition or make a repair disc.

I pulled his HD and plugged it as external drive into my PC and can view all his files so I assume the HD is ok.

I also booted his PC to Hiren's ver 14.1 and did the reset MBR and still the same message.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the BIOS or UEFI to see if it even detects the hard drive hardware.  If not, check the connection type and switch between ATA & AHCI.

This is for a Dell laptop forum, but explains the differences between those two types.  I have seen this setting get "magically" flipped, preventing proper boot: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/18628263